# Could you call a team "prolific"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

As in, a team that's producing a lot of value for the organisation. Producing value.

Can such a team be called *prolific*, or is there perhaps a better term for it?

Comment: It depends on the sport:  cricket batsman (or even baseball batters) could be called prolific because they are scoring lots of goals.  A four-man bob sleigh team or competitive general knowledge team couldn't.  Why?  because 'prolificity' in competitions involves scoring lots of points (by touch downs, runs or whatever).

Answer (score 6):

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/prolific) defines *prolific* like this:

> producing a great number or amount of something:
> *He was probably the most prolific songwriter of his generation. Rabbits and other rodents are prolific (= have lots of babies).*

Your proposed usage, for example

> The team has been more prolific this year than last year.

doesn't, by itself, leave clear what the something is that's being produced in great number or amount.  That's a problem.

But if the context makes it clear, then it could be okay.  For example:

> The chart shows the number of big-ticket sales made this quarter by each team. As you can see, the recently formed Bradley team was the most prolific team this quarter.

Also, although that dictionary definition didn't include my next point, I think the *something* generally has to be countable.  "Value" sounds funny, partly because we don't count it, and also because it sounds quite vague.  We'd need to know how it's defined -- what's being counted or measured, and how.

I do not agree with @Xanne that all the production has to be of the same type.

> John was incredibly prolific with both his composing and his painting during the shutdown.

Answer (score 4):

The team itself can be productive.

The team's goal production can be prolific.

Comment: I admire the simplicity and clarity of this answer. I think we can call a painter prolific if she paints many paintings a year. So a team could be prolific if its productivity rate is high.

Comment: Productive definitely sounds natural for a team in a workplace. *Productivity* is the measure of how much they produce.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Prolific artists produce a lot of art. Prolific goal scorers produce a lot of goals. Prolific authors, text. Prolific teams produce .... ?

Comment: Prolific teams produce volumes of usable documentation, terrific applications with engaging user experience, and handsomely organized Wikis.

Comment: @YosefBaskin So, various and multiple things. That’s the main point here.

Comment: Prolific does not include the concept of variety. A prolific writer may produce many books all in the same genre.

Comment: The team itself can also be prolific, why not? Anything that produces things can be called prolific if it produces a lot of whatever it produces. "Goal production", on the other hand, is not something that _produces_ and therefore cannot be _prolific_. You could say that "a prolific team is a team that is very productive" but not "This team has \*prolific goal production", that makes no sense.

Comment: Here are a few hundred examples of the phrase "prolific team" used in [printed works](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22prolific+team%22&tbm=bks&ei=cArIYvu2M8y39u8P8-iG4Ao&ved=0ahUKEwj7rsGKjun4AhXMm_0HHXO0AawQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22prolific+team%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQiAVYxQ9ghBFoAHAAeACAAXGIAa8CkgEDMi4xmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books) and [a few thousand more](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22prolific%20team%22) found on the internet. It is a perfectly common and standard use of the word _prolific_.